# How do you download from a URL that takes data from a session in R

Tags: r, csv, data-science

The title is a bit confusing but I'll be more specific. I have a store on RedBubble.com, and each sale made on the website is recorded by them. When a user is signed in, they can navigate to [www.redbubble.com/account/sales/by_sale](http://www.redbubble.com/account/sales/by_sale) to view a tabulated version of these sales. Also, on the same page there is a link to download all of this data in CSV format.

[image]

I would like to download this file remotely from an R script, but the url for this file is simply "www.redbubble.com/account/sales/by_sale.csv" and has no information in the url as to which profile to download from (Understandably due to privacy/security/etc)

```
url <- "https://www.redbubble.com/account/sales/by_sale.csv"
dest_file <- "data/redbubble.csv"
download.file(url, destfile = dest_file)
```

In R (above), downloading just this url results in a 406 error. **Is there a way to somehow relay session/login credentials in a 'get' request to access this file in R?**

Comment: You can't use `download.file` directly. You need to basically script a web browser. The [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RSelenium) package along with [rvest](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rvest) can help with that.

Comment: That site uses Google's reCAPTCHA. You can't see it, but it does and will pop it up on occasion esp when it detects automation. RSelenium isn't going to help get past that. Anything you write is ultimately going to break. It _may_ be possible to save a session token from a successful auth (it does have a "remember me" on login) but you'd have to get that token and pass that properly.